# Sublime Text 2 build command ignores the shebang

Tags: sublimetext2, shebang

The Sublime text 2.0.1 (Mac OSX) build command ignores the shebang line a the top of my python file.
The shebang line has the full path to my python 3.2 installation :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

However the python version being used is always 2.7.2. I'm maintaining code for both 2.7 and 3.2 and so must rely on the shebang line to be used.

Is there a way to configure the Sublime text 2 build system to look at the shebang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime does not use the shebang to determine the execution, it uses your build rule.  You could customize the Python build rule to add **variants** for python2 and python3.

- [Official instructions for adding build variants.](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#variants)
- [Simplified example of build variants from another SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13888669/1309332)

Note that with build variants, the default is run by <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Windows and Linux).  The second variant can be run <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Windows and Linux).

Comment: I changed Python.sublime-build to point to the full path of python3, and now I can build with python 3.

Shame on Sublime Text for not supporting the shebang.

BTW on Mac OS, the Python.sublime-build can be found in:
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build

Comment: You should be sure to add your build rule to Packages/User. That way your customizations will not be overridden the next time you upgrade Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Sublime Text Shebang](https://github.com/samizdatco/sublime-text-shebang) plugin.

It adds a few commands that allow to run scripts, based on the shebang line, but the output will be placed on a new buffer, not in the console.